# What version of WebKit does Adobe Air use?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, webkit, air

In the most recent release of Adobe Air, what version of the WebKit rendering engine does it use?

Answer (score 7):

> AIR 1.5.2 includes WebKit version
>   34190.

[Release notes / Version Information](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/air/1_5_2/releasenotes_developers.html#versioninfo)

Answer (score 4):

A very simple bit of JavaScript will tell you that:

```
alert(navigator.userAgent)
```

Answer (score 2):

Air 2.0 comes with a new WebKit version

> WebKit in AIR is based on the version shipped with Safari 4.0.3

[Here for more info](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/AIR_2:Release_Notes#New_Features_in_AIR_2)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Alert.show(html.htmlLoader.userAgent);

Where html is id of the component